# My App is running fine locally, but when it is deployed to Render it has some stuff that doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, render

I have an app that I am working on for a coding bootcamp. It is done and everything is working fine locally, but when it is deployed, the edit button and seat button lead to "not found". This is the page. https://reservation-app-eoob.onrender.com/dashboard I think it has something to do with my backend application. I am not too sure what I should be looking for and would like some help narrowing down my options. The buttons are working fine when run locally so I don't think it is in my code.

I tried changing the backend deployment because that's where I believe my issues are, but to no avail.